# Multiple observable in Route guard but wait for only one - Angular 5

Tags: angular, angular5, observable, angular-route-guards

I have a route guard in my application in which i need to check for two observables if anyone is success i should allow the route or block.

Route guard :

```
canActivate(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, state: RouterStateSnapshot): any {
return (this.isValid().map(valid => {
            console.log(valid);
            return valid;
        }) || this.isValidFromApi().map(valid => {
            console.log(valid);
            return valid;
        }));
} //how to achieve something like this
}
private isValid() {
        return this.service.details.map(resp => {
            console.log(resp);
            if (resp.data) {
                return true;
            } else {
                return false;
            }
        });
    }

    private isValidFromApi() {
        return this.service.getKeys().map((response) => {
            console.log(response);
            if (response) {
                return true;
            } else {
return false;
            });
        }
```

So if anyone of isValid() or isValidFromApi() return true the route guard canActivate should be active. How to achieve this? I don't want to wait for both the calls to complete because this.service.details is actually a BehaviorSubject which holds the response of this.service.getKeys().

Is there any other way to achieve this??

Thanks in advance